# On Bedrock edition, how do you paste into a book with a controller?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have successfully copied The Bee Movie script with my Xbox One controller, I've pasted it in messages, but when I opened Minecraft and tried pasting it into a book, It wouldn't let me paste it into there. Anyone know how to paste it into a book? The normal method doesn't work for some reason and I want to have The Bee Movie script on Minecraft so I can book ban my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's better to do is to copy-paste it somewhere else that it won't crash your system. Then try pasting the pieces 1 by 1, as long as you don't crash it in the process.

If you have the entire script, of course, it won't be posted all in 1. It will definitely crash because it is way too long.

Make a test world and do the instructions above.

Comment: the problem is i want to crash my friends game by giving him a shulker full of bee movie scripts

Comment: also, if you paste a thing of text larger than a page, will it fill all of the pages it needs or will it just fill 1 page?

Comment: Yeah, but what you should try to do is to slowly copy-paste the small pieces 1 by 1. If your system won't crash in the process, it's fine. Just keep the book open though. I'm sure bad effects could happen.

Comment: It will still fill up the whole page. You just can't see the text.

Comment: will it only fill 1 page or the whole book?

Comment: Copy-pasting the whole thing or even bit by bit on the same page will still only fill 1.

Comment: tbh, i might get one of my friends with the random book text exploit and they can do that on a book, give it to me, and do it that way.

Comment: the thing that fills all 50 pages with random characters

Comment: here's the thing tho, it wont let me copy paste into a book normally so i need to know why and how to do it

Comment: So how do you actually paste into a minecraft book?

Comment: I don't actually play on Controller, so I don't know, try looking up how to copy-paste something in XBox. Also, we have to end this discussion. I can't chat in SE Chat right now.